# Inclusion of header file

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, header-files

I am working on Ubuntu 14.04 and my kernel version is 3.13.0-46-generic. I want to include a file named `power_supply_core.c` in my kernel module.

The location (supposedly) for this file is `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-46-generic/drivers/power/power_supply_core.c`. But on my system, at the mentioned path, I can't locate this file (not sure if hidden or what).

I got this location from the link: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=3.13;i=__power_supply_is_system_supplied

My first question is, how to include this file in my kernel module since it is not in include directory?

Second question is, what should I do if file indeed doesn't exist on my system?

Comment: `drivers/power/power_supply_core.c` isn't a header file. It's part of the source code of Linux.

Comment: Can you tell us what you're trying to do? Do you want to call `power_supply_is_system_supplied()` (without underscores)? Then you have to include `linux/power_supply.h` (`/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-46/include/linux/power_supply.h`).

Comment: I want to use the function "class_for_each_device" in which last parameter is a function call to "__power_supply_is_system_supplied".

Comment: So basically [`power_supply_is_system_supplied()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/power/power_supply_core.c?v=3.13#L291)?